# Find gradient for a 2D slice of a 3D function

Tags: geometry, derivatives

I've got a mathematical problem that should have a general solution, but trying to solve it with mathematical software tools like Wolfram/Mathematica/Matlab etc. gave either complex or no solutions, although it might just be my limited skills using the software, especially defining constrains for variables.

The first stage of the problem is quite easy. Look at this function:

[image]

The black part is the function itself, the grey parts are help elements. The small line in the middle is the center, $x = 0$. The two circles have radius $r_c$ and centers at $x=\pm r_b$, so the function is:

$ f_{2D}(x) = z = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad \text{if } |x| < r_b\\ \sqrt{r_c^2 - (x - r_b)^2} & \quad \text{if } r_b < |x| < r_b + r_c\\ \end{cases}$

Note that I call it $z$, not $y$, because we'll need $y$ in the second stage.

We now get a gradient, let's call it $g$ and we want to know the $x$ where $f_{2D}'(x) = g$. This is very easy to solve, just calculate the derivation of $f$ and you're done. It is possible to find a closed formula with parameters $x, r_b, r_c, g$ and solutions for $f_{2D}'(x) = g$.

Anyway, here's the second stage, we go to 3D space and rotate the function around it's center (around the $z$ axis) After this, we want to get a 2D slice of this parallel to the $x$ axis. Again, I'll try to visualize it crudely, at the top is the previous image, below it is a top-down view in the $xy$ plane:

[image]

Note that only the light blue part is interesting, as in the white center, $z = 0$ everywhere. If we now look at the slices defined by lines parallel to $x$ (one of them is in the image in green), every slice is a functions $f_{3D}(x, y)$ with $f_{3D}(x, 0) = f_{2D}(x)$.

Surprisingly, finding solutions for $f'_{3D}(x, y) = g$ for a given $y$ seems to be much harder. Especially since I'm trying to generalize it for the variables $r_b$ and $r_c$ and would prefer a closed formula instead of numerical solutions.

I hope the problem is quite clear, my visualizing and LaTeX skills are a bit rusty :)

Can anybody give solutions for this using mathematical software and/or hints how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we agree with the configuration below,

[image]

as the centers of the circles are $(\mp r_b,r_c)$ we have

$$
f_{2D}(x)=\begin{cases}
r_c-\sqrt{r_c^2-(x+r_b)^2}, & -r_b-r_c\le x<-r_b\\
0, & -r_b\le x\le -r_b\\ 
r_c-\sqrt{r_c^2-(x-r_b)^2}, & r_b< x\le r_b+r_c
\end{cases}
$$
We can parametrize the surface of revolution when $f_{2D}$ is rotated around $z$-axis using the cylindrical polar coordinates $z,\phi$ as parameters.
$$
x=\left(r_b+\sqrt{r_c^2-(r_c-z)^2}\right)\cos\phi\\
y=\left(r_b+\sqrt{r_c^2-(r_c-z)^2}\right)\sin\phi
$$ 
Note that this parametrization ignores the part of the surface revolution that is on $z=0$ plane and intersects
$$
\{\;(x,y):x^2+y^2<r_b^2\;\}
$$
So this parametrization captures only the "interesting" part. Using this parametrization it's possible to write down $f_{3D}(x,y)$ in terms of $x,y$
$$
x^2+y^2=\left(r_b+\sqrt{r_c^2-(r_c-z)^2}\right)^2\\
\implies \color{blue}{f_{3D}(x,y)=z=r_c-\sqrt{r_c^2-\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-r_b\right)^2}}
$$
Note that
$$
f_{3D}(x,0)=\begin{cases}
r_c-\sqrt{r_c^2-\left(x-r_b\right)^2},&\text{when }x>0\\
r_c-\sqrt{r_c^2-\left(x+r_b\right)^2},&\text{when }x<0
\end{cases}
\;=f_{2D}(x)
$$
just as was expected from $f_{3D}$. Lastly, gradient of $f_{3D}$ is given by
$$
\nabla f_{3D}={\partial f_{3D}\over\partial x}\hat{i}+{\partial f_{3D}\over\partial y}\hat{j}={(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-r_b)(x\hat{i}+y\hat{j})\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(r_c-f_{3D}(x,y))}
$$

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could be helpfull for you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html

You want to have
$$g(y,r_b,r_c)=x \Leftrightarrow \nabla f(x,y,r_b,r_c)=\delta$$
for given $$y,r_b,r_c,\delta$$

I think there is no analytic solution for g, so you have to solve it numericly. For example you can use something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method, because the derivation is monoton increasing. If you improve your proceed, you can reduce the trials for more accurate solutions.